# postGIS schema qualifier - best practice

Tags: postgresql, postgis

There are a number of cases where the EXTENSION for postGIS is created iwth a schema qualifier.

```
CREATE SCHEMA postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION PostGIS WITH SCHEMA postgis;
```

why is that?  what are the tradeoffs in using the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A schema is like a namespace in programming. It lets you have different things with the same name.

For example, you might have a function foo() in your public schema. If PostGIS has a function foo() as well, that wouldn't work without name qualification.

Comment: I understand clearly now. This avoids potential duplication of functions, particularly as one may NOT be aware of them, as can be reasonably expected.  Need to avoid duplication of PostGIS installation now!